# Italics in LaTeX (e. g. when using Tikz)

Tags: fonts, tikz-styles

`\bfseries` is for bolding but what is for italics in tikz?

*Example where italics needed for "Not SP graph"*.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=white, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt] 

\draw (0,0) node(in){in}--(1,0) node{}--(2,0) node(b){b}--(5,0) node(e){e}--(6,0) node{}--(7,0) node(out){out};
\node[rectangle,font=\bfseries] at (3.5,-1.7) {Not SP graph};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font styles in your document are defined by the class document or by a package or by you in the preamble or in your document. The  font style used in the environment tikzpicture   is the font style defined when you enter in the picture. You can change the style in the part of text in a node with `font= ...`

> Dimensions like 1em will be with respect to the font used outside the
>   node (usually the font that was in force when the picture started)

Like David wrote finally the font styles are defined in latex and Tikz do not change anything.

Comment: This font=... is not helpful. How do you actually make the font, e.g., italic shape when declaring the style?

Answer (score 11):

`\itshape` is the command for italics (this and `\bfseries` are unrelated to tikz)

Comment: Where are the font styles defined?

Comment: @hhh they are defined in latex

Comment: Thank you, found a manual [here](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/schmidt/schmidt.pdf).